# JavaFX wait for Webview fully load or cancel everything after 15 seconds

Tags: javafx, webview

I am writing on a nfcreader programm in JavaFX. Using ACR122U nfcreader and the nfcreader class found on github. It works as expected, for now I am holding the card to the reader and after the card uid is read it loads a webpage from our server and shows information.

Problem:

- the NFC reader is running in a background task and always fires if a card is hold on the reader.
  I need to prevent this - while the webpage is loading.

What I did:

- if the nfcread service succeeds it calls a method "loadZeitdatenToWebview(nfcuid)"
- in this method a variable is set to true to tell Java that the webview still loads data
- I am setting this variable to false  if the Workerstate of the webview succeeds otherwise its true... for a amount of 15 seconds checked by a pausetransition - if I get no webview "success" within 15 seconds it cancels the whole nfcread and tells the user there is no connection to the
  server - so far
- it works as it should if I have no connection to the server it stops the nfcread and everything is fine
- but if I get a webview success - it works only once ... I have to wait for 15 seconds (from the pause transition) till it reads again and shows me the webpage.
  So pause transition isn't the best way to achieve whar I need :( - but what else can be used ?
  in short: readnfc -> get uid from card -> webview calls a page dep. on the uid -> no other nfcreader should be possible till webpage is fully loaded and shwon to the user -> if there is no connection to the server after 15 seconds stop everything ...

Code for the nfcread succeeded... :

```
 nfcread.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() { //if service succeeded

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            labelReaderStatus.setText("NFC Readerstatus: warte auf NFC");
            labelReaderStatusInfo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: WHITE; -fx-text-fill: black;");
            labelReaderStatusInfo.setText("warte...");

            System.out.println("NFC UID Card: " + nfcread.getValue()); //return value from service nfcread
            if (nfcread.getValue() != "" && nfcread.getValue() != "Error" && nfcread.getValue() != null && nfcread.getValue() != "Error no Card") {
                uidRead = nfcread.getValue();

                labelReaderStatusInfo.setText("NFC Chip wurde gelesen - beginne mit Auswertung ");
                labelReaderStatusInfo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: GREEN; -fx-text-fill: white;");
                //chekc if webengine still loads data if not loadmethod
                //loadData to webview

                if (!waitForData) {
                loadZeitdatenToWebview(uidRead);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Still loading data for "+uidRead);
                    nfcread.reset();

                }


            } //wenn uidRead keinen Fehler und nicht leer ist
            else if (nfcread.getValue() == "Error") {...
```

and here the code for wait for webview or stop ...

```
//start webengine
private void loadZeitdatenToWebview(String uid) {


    //wait till page loaded:
    engine = webviewer.getEngine();
    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {


        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.out.println("Workerstate Succeeded");
            System.out.println("waitforData: " +waitForData );
            // new page has loaded, process:
            this.waitForData = false;
            zeiterfassungErfolgreich();

            System.out.println("waitforData done reset: " +waitForData );

                }
        if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() != Worker.State.RUNNING) {
            System.out.println("Workerstate Running ");
            System.out.println("load state while data request:" + engine.getLoadWorker().getState()); //SCHEDULED
            this.waitForData = true;
            zeiterfassungRunning();
        }

    });

    engine.load(httpHostforZeiterfassung + uid);
    //engine.load("http://10.0.0.11/nfcread.php?uid=" + uid);
    System.out.println("here: " + engine.getLoadWorker().getState());
}


private void zeiterfassungErfolgreich() {
    System.out.println("zeiterfassungErfolgreich");
    System.out.println("Fertig:" +waitForData);
    labelReaderStatusInfo.setText("Zeiterfassung erfolgreich...");
    //nfcread.reset();
}

private void zeiterfassungRunning() {
    System.out.println("zeiterfassungRunning check - for data within 15 seconds");
    //engine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(15));

    if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
        if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {pause.stop(); waitForData=false; }
        else {
            engine.executeScript("window.stop()");
            waitForData = false;
            labelReaderStatusInfo.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;  -fx-text-fill: white;");
            labelReaderStatusInfo.setText("Error keine Verbindung zum Server!");
            nfcread.cancel();
        }
        //System.out.println("Running:" +waitForData);
    });
    pause.play();
    System.out.println("here2: " + engine.getLoadWorker().getState());


}


//end webengine
```

If I can use the pausetransition this way how can I prevent the waiting time if webview succeeded or better what should I use to make this work ?
Thanks to @all here !!

Additional Info:
my actual code gives me this output if I try to nfcread a card within those 15 seconds:

- Waiting for a card..
- Failed OFF
- Event: 0BDF8D69
- load state while data request:SCHEDULED
- zeiterfassungRunning check - for data within 15 seconds
- here2: SCHEDULED
- here: RUNNING
- Waiting for a card..
- zeiterfassungErfolgreich
- Fertig:true
- load state while data request:SUCCEEDED
- zeiterfassungRunning check - for data within 15 seconds
- here2: SUCCEEDED
- Failed OFF
- Event: 0BDF8D69
- Still loading dataWaiting for a card. << last line shows me that it is not allowed to load new content ...

Comment: I would suggest reusing the same `PauseTransition`, that way you can stop and restart it at will. You may also be able to do away with the `waitForData` field and simply query the `getEngine().getLoadWorker().isRunning()` method. And you need to be careful with how you're adding your listener. Each time the `loadZeitdatenToWebview` method is invoked you add a new listener to the worker without removing the older listener. You should only add the listener once, probably when you first create the `WebView`.

Comment: And you should stop the `PauseTransition` when the worker succeeds. That all being said, I'm having trouble seeing what forces you to wait for 15 seconds even if the load succeeds (especially if you rewrite your code to stop the transition upon completion). You set `waitForData` to `false` when the load succeeds, so I'm not sure what's preventing you from loading the next set of data. Could you clarify?

Comment: HI! Slaw thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am stopping the Pausetransition here: Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) { pause.stop(); or not? << sorry I am really new to all of this... Javastuff. So I thought the pausetransition is stopped completely when I am calling .stop(), -> what should I write there to stop the pausetransition? @your second comment thats what I want to prevent I don't want to wait 15 seconds ... if the page is loaded successfully - I use this only for timeout if the page cant be reached. Or is there a better way.

Comment: I will now rewrite it to getloadWorker.isRunning instead of "waitforData" :) I didn't think of checking if the webview loaded is running :)  -

Comment: Your code is confusing. If I understand you correctly, here is what I would do. I would create a `Worker.State` variable with class scope. I would call `loadZeitdatenToWebview(uidRead);` I would create a `Timeline` that runs every second and set the cycle count to 15.  In the `Timeline`, I would check to see if the `Worker.State` variable got updated by the engine listener.

Comment: hey Sedrick, yes I know - thats also for me confusing :) .. theres my lack of knowledge about writing good code :( sorry for that. you understood me correctly and I will rewrite the code tomorrow - and get back here - I think both of you sent me to the right track - thanks for now and good night - I will reply to both of you tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: You have that call to `stop()` in the `setOnFinished` handler, so it's only called when the animation is finished (making the call to `stop()` rather useless). And I understand you don't want to wait 15 seconds if the load succeeds. What I don't understand is how your _current_ code forces you to wait the 15 seconds when the load succeeds.

Comment: @Slaw - but how do I stop or cancel the Paustransition if the webview.load succeeds ? - I think the problem is the waitforData variable - that prevents me to get the new webpage... I think there is the error.

Comment: "how do I stop or cancel the `Paustransition` if the `webview.load` succeeds?" -> Check the [`WebEngine` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) to see how to do something when loading is successful.  Then call [`stop()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#stop()) on the pause transition in the appropriate handler method.  Note: Sedrick just wrote an answer which does just that.

Comment: moved to question...

Comment: Edit the question to add the additional information in a well-formatted way rather than using a comment for that.  Otherwise it is hard to read and hard to follow, plus comments are limited in space, so it can be hard to fit the appropriate info in a comment.  If needed you can also add a comment to notify that you edited the question.

Comment: ok without confusing you guys now more and more I will rewrite my code tomorrow and come backto you tomorrow ! Thanks to all of you!!

Answer (score 4):

There's at least a couple problems in your code that may be contributing to your overall problem.

1. You don't stop the `PauseTransition` when the load succeeds (or fails).

   It looks like there's an attempt to implement this, but you do it in the `onFinished` handler of the animation. That handler is invoked when the animation has finished and is thus already stopped/stopping. To call `stop()` inside that handler is basically a no-op.

   It would probably be easier to reuse a single `PauseTransition` instance and simply start and stop it based on the running state of the load worker (e.g. by observing the worker's `running` property). You can also probably use the running status of the worker instead of your own `waitForData` flag.
2. You add a new listener to the worker's `state` property every time you load a new web page, but you don't remove the old listeners.

   This means the work inside the listener is repeated, where the number of times it's repeated increases over time. You should only add the listener once when you are first initializing everything.

In some ways I believe you're thinking too linearly. Typically GUI programming is *event-driven* which is inherently asynchronous.

Here's a skeleton example of what I was hinting at above and in the question comments. You'll obviously need to rewrite things in order to integrate it into your application, but it should help you understand what's happening and hopefully find a solution.

```java
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Foo {

  private final String baseUrl;
  private final PauseTransition timeout;
  private final WebView webView;

  public Foo(String baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    timeout = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(15));
    webView = new WebView();

    Worker<?> worker = webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker();
    // observe 'running' property to start/stop timeout
    worker.runningProperty().addListener(this::loaderRunningChanged);
    // observe 'state' property to handle success/failure
    worker.stateProperty().addListener(this::loaderStateChanged);

    timeout.setOnFinished(
        e -> {
          worker.cancel(); // stop trying to load
          handleTimeout();
        });
  }

  public void loadData(String uid) {
    if (!webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().isRunning()) {
      webView.getEngine().load(baseUrl + uid);
    }
  }

  private void loaderRunningChanged(
      ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, boolean wasRunning, boolean isRunning) {
    if (isRunning) {
      System.out.println("Loading...");
      timeout.playFromStart(); // restart timeout countdown
    } else {
      timeout.stop(); // load completed, stop timeout countdown
    }
  }

  private void loaderStateChanged(
      ObservableValue<? extends State> obs, State oldState, State newState) {
    // switch expressions standardized in Java 14 (preview feature in Java 12 and 13)
    switch (newState) {
      case SUCCEEDED -> handleSuccess();
      case FAILED -> handleFailure();
    }
  }

  private void handleSuccess() {
    System.out.println("Load succeeded.");
    // ...
  }

  private void handleFailure() {
    System.out.println("Load failed.");
    // ...
  }

  private void handleTimeout() {
    System.out.println("Load timeout.");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: hey Slaw - your answer is working perfectly for me. Yes you are right I thought and still thinking too linear ... I have to remember to react on every possible event ... or event combination. :) - and have to learn much more abvout eventhandlers and their init. Thank you very very much for your help!!!

Comment: and let me know a adress there I can send you  some money for a beer :) or whatever u like! you both saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what I think you should do.

1. Try to load the engine.
2. Create a global `Worker.State` variable that will be used to keep up with the state of the stateProperty listener. Use a `Timeline` to check the value of the `Worker.State` variable every second for 15 seconds.

```
/*
Code found here -> http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/webview.html
*/
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Worker.State workerState;
    Timeline oneSecondWonder;
    
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");

        WebView webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            workerState = newState;
        });        
        webView.getEngine().load("http://google5.com");//Use to see what happens after 15 seconds.
        //webView.getEngine().load("http://google.com");//Use to see what happens before 15 seconds.
        
        oneSecondWonder = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                     System.out.println("Worker State: " + workerState);
                     switch(workerState)
                     {
                         case FAILED:
                             System.out.println("FAILED");
                             break;
                         case SUCCEEDED:
                             System.out.println("SUCCEEDED");
                             oneSecondWonder.stop();
                             System.out.println("I am stopping the Timeline and moving forward with code here!");
                             oneSecondWonder.stop();
                             //Next set of code here!
                             break;
                         case CANCELLED:
                             //Code here if needed!
                             break;
                         //Other cases if needed here!
                     }
        }));
        oneSecondWonder.setOnFinished((t) -> {
            System.out.println("The Timeline ended. I am alerting the user about his/her next options");
        });        
        oneSecondWonder.setCycleCount(15);
        oneSecondWonder.play();
        
        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: oh man Thanks Sedrick... !!!! I will implement that or better will try to understand and use it the right way in my code !! Thank you!!

Comment: Personally I think the use of `Timeline` here is more complicated than it needs to be, but that's just an opinion. @loomy [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/tkslaw/7268eefc3619c29122f9f7fed560c679) of what I was hinting at in the question comments. It's only a skeleton class that shows that basics of what I meant. You'd have to rewrite some things to integrate it into your application. Note: I will likely delete the gist eventually.

Comment: @Slaw I'd advise taking the gist and posting it as an answer rather than deleting the gist.  The solution is different enough and adds enough value while also answering the question, that it would be fine to do so and could be posted without a lot of additional explanation.

Comment: @jewelsea Added an answer.

Comment: hey Sedrick I first tried to implement your solution - it was working so far but if I tapped the card too often/fast to the reader it got stuck and stopped working as it should - so I stopped working on that and implemented Slaws solution and this was working "out of the box" - and still works if I stress the reader. But I like your solution a little more because of seeing whats happening, right now its for me easier to understand than Slaws solution - I will go on for now - and will retry to implement your solution in a couple of days. :) Thank you soo much for your help!

Comment: @Sedrick and let me  know a adress there I can send you  some money for a beer :) or whatever u like! you both saved my day!

Comment: Sorry, my solution did not work for you. I am glad Slaw's answer did. Thanks for the beer offer. I am more than happy to help where I can for free.